# Filtered water in a glass container

Tags: water, filter

So I'm tired of carrying mineral water bottles and recycling the glass. I'd like to switch to filtered tap water, but I'd like to avoid the plastic jug and the plastic container in which the filtering material is sold (from that famous and well-established brand—left of the picture).

[image: plastic water filter and a glass jug]

I'm considering the following idea. Carefully slice open the plastic filter container, take the beads, which are apparently a combination of a polymer and activater charcoal, to absorb this and that undesirable elements, and put them in a glass container (right of the picture). Glass is guaranteed not to transfer chemicals and can be dropped in the dishwasher for cleaning.

Have you tried something like this? Can you think of any reason why it may be imprudent to do it? The activated charcoal is available on the market by itself, but it's unclear where I'd buy the polymers that absorb the other half of the undesirable elements, and the strong brand name is reassuring regarding the composition of the filtering material (although I'd rather avoid drinking water that sat in a plastic container, regardless of the brand of the plastic).

Comment: Look up "Mixed Bed Ion Exchange Resin" You want decent quality. It'll turn your Ca and Fe to Na ions, and your SO4 to Cl ions. Readily available online, often as refills for existing mineral absorbers. That said, I'd go straight reverse osmosis, if the water supply is clean enough not to plug membranes. That'll get you water at about 8ppm solids, and no NaCl buildup. My tap runs 240ppm. -Research it before starting. Someone may already have exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you could get a faucet filtration system and a glass jug. This is basically a water filter that clips onto your faucet. No taking things apart, and no water sitting in a plastic jug.

Comment: Go big or go home, +1.